# Can't get Unity to log-in, instantly crashes to main Login screen

Tags: unity, login, cinnamon, 13.10

Recently did a clean install of 13.10, everything was going great. Then I installed the new Cinnamon 2.0 Desktop from the PPA. When I logged in, it seemed to work (except that it didn't register touch's on the clickpad as clicks). Afterwards, I logged out of Cinnamon to log back into Unity, but it immediately crashes back to the Login screen. I can log into GNOME flashback without issue. I've removed Cinnamon, but the problem still persists.

Comment: you've been luckier than i was, I tried removing cinnamon and now it won't boot even in gnome fallback

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it solved like this

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove cinnamon
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
```

Try it